# Docker (Moby) golang image build logs are base64 encoded

Tags: docker, go

I'm looking for help with extracting the image build logs from a dockerd (buildkit/moby) image build request sent by a Golang based client using the docker client libraries.

I can request the image build fine and receive the log stream of json messages then decode them as [Jsonmessage](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/pkg/jsonmessage/jsonmessage.go) instances. But the actual log lines from the builder appear to be base64 encoded in an [`aux` field of each json message](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/pkg/jsonmessage/jsonmessage.go#L150).

I can decode the base64 easily enough, but they seem to include odd terminal control characters and possibly mis-encoded data, which makes me wonder if they're actually a base64 encoding of some kind of struct I'm supposed to unpack.

What confuses me is that I can't find anything in the docker-ce or moby code that seems to base64-decode an 'aux' payload when processing logs when displaying build progress for `docker buildx build`.

As far as I can tell, the buildx code doesn't do anything special to the `aux` payload: https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/523cf7e71252013fbb6a590be67a54b4a88c1dae/components/cli/cli/command/image/build_buildkit.go#L325

For example, trimmed-down build code like:

```
        image := Image{Name:      "test"}
        contextreader, err := archive.TarWithOptions(buildConf.Build.Context, &archive.TarOptions{})
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        imageBuildResponse, err := b.client.ImageBuild(
                ctx,
                contextreader,
                types.ImageBuildOptions{
                      Version:     types.BuilderBuildKit,
                      Context:     contextreader,
                      Dockerfile:  dockerfile,
                })
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        defer imageBuildResponse.Body.Close()


        buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)

        imageID := ""
        writeAux := func(msg jsonmessage.JSONMessage) {
                if msg.ID == "moby.image.id" {
                        var result types.BuildResult
                        if err := json.Unmarshal(*msg.Aux, &result); err != nil {
                            panic("don't do this in your real code")
                        }
                        imageID = result.ID
                        return
                }
                return err
        }

        err := jsonmessage.DisplayJSONMessagesStream(imageBuildResponse.Body, buf, os.Stderr.Fd(), false /* not terminal */, writeAux)
        if err != nil {
                if jerr, ok := err.(*jsonmessage.JSONError); ok {
                        // If no error code is set, default to 1
                        if jerr.Code == 0 {
                                jerr.Code = 1
                        }
                        return fmt.Errorf("error while building image: %s", jerr.Message)
                }
        }
```

will write json payloads to stderr like

```
{"id":"moby.buildkit.trace","aux":"Cn0KR3NoYTI1NjozZThhMzMxYmRkZGFjNWZkYmNjOGVhMDFmYWFhYmM3MjA0MDkwMmYwNjdmYzRhOGY0NDJmMmIzYWVlN2RkNGIyGiRbaW50ZXJuYWxdIGxvYWQgcmVtb3RlIGJ1aWxkIGNvbnRleHQqDAiYw8KaBhCykpCqAg=="}
{"id":"moby.buildkit.trace","aux":"CokBCkdzaGEyNTY6M2U4YTMzMWJkZGRhYzVmZGJjYzhlYTAxZmFhYWJjNzIwNDA5MDJmMDY3ZmM0YThmNDQyZjJiM2FlZTdkZDRiMhokW2ludGVybmFsXSBsb2FkIHJlbW90ZSBidWlsZCBjb250ZXh0KgwImMPCmgYQspKQqgIyCgiZw8KaBhD08F0="}
```

The base64 strings here don't decode as valid utf-8, and they don't make sense as ISO-8859-1 either. E.g. with a utf-8 console encoding:

```
$ base64 -d <<<'Cn0KR3NoYTI1NjozZThhMzMxYmRkZGFjNWZkYmNjOGVhMDFmYWFhYmM3MjA0MDkwMmYwNjdmYzRhOGY0NDJmMmIzYWVlN2RkNGIyGiRbaW50ZXJuYWxdIGxvYWQgcmVtb3RlIGJ1aWxkIGNvbnRleHQqDAiYw8KaBhCykpCqAg=='

}
Gsha256:3e8a331bdddac5fdbcc8ea01faaabc72040902f067fc4a8f442f2b3aee7dd4b2�$[internal] load remote build context*
                                                                                                              ������
```

It looks like it's probably a struct, but for the life of me I can't find what decodes and processes it.

Answer (score 1):

So of course I find the answer while writing up the SO question...

The `writeAux` function in `build_buildkit.go` calls [the `write` method of a `tracer` instance](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/523cf7e71252013fbb6a590be67a54b4a88c1dae/components/cli/cli/command/image/build_buildkit.go#L386), and that does the real work. I must've been blind.

The messages are serialized instances of `StatusResponse` from the `github.com/moby/buildkit/api/services/control` package. They are unmarshalled from base64-decoded byte sequences and inspected. If you want logs and to skip everything else, just look for instances with non-empty `Logs` member arrays, e.g. something like this within the above `writeAux` function:

```
                } else if msg.ID == "moby.buildkit.trace" {
                        // Process the message like
                        // https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/523cf7e71252013fbb6a590be67a54b4a88c1dae/components/cli/cli/command/image/build_buildkit.go#L386
                        // the 'tracer.write' method in build_buildkit.go
                        var resp controlapi.StatusResponse
                        var dt []byte
                        // ignoring all messages that are not understood
                        if err := json.Unmarshal(*msg.Aux, &dt); err != nil {
                                return
                        }
                        if err := (&resp).Unmarshal(dt); err != nil {
                                return
                        }
                        for _, v := range resp.Vertexes {
                                fmt.Printf("layer: %+v", v)
                        }
                        for _, v := range resp.Statuses {
                                fmt.Printf("status: %+v", v)
                        }
                        for _, v := range resp.Logs {
                                fmt.Printf("log: msg.Msg)
                        }
                  }
```

The `json.Unmarshal` and `controlapi.StatusResponse.Unmarshal` do the base64 decoding and unpacking for you.